# How to start with cryptocurrency?

Tags: cryptocurrency, money-market

Understanding Forex and crypto trading:
*Currency Pairs:*
*Forex involves trading currency pairs, such as EUR/USD (Euro/US Dollar) or GBP/JPY (British Pound/Japanese Yen).*
*The first currency in the pair is the base currency, and the second is the quote currency.*
*Exchange Rate Movements:*
*Exchange rates fluctuate due to various factors, including economic indicators, geopolitical events, and market sentiment.*
*Traders aim to predict these movements to profit from buying low and selling high.*
*Getting Started:*
*Educate Yourself:*
*Learn the basics of forex trading, including market terminology, order types, and analysis methods. *
*Utilize online resources, courses, and reputable trading platforms that offer educational materials. Is a url link of a good forex and crypto trading course **CZ Stake - Mask Money Vibes* (https://aff.stakecut.com/543223/9545110)
*Choose a Reliable Broker:*
*Select a reputable forex broker with a user-friendly platform, competitive spreads, and regulatory compliance.*
*Ensure the broker provides essential tools for analysis and execution.*
*Create a Trading Plan:*
*Develop a comprehensive trading plan that includes your risk tolerance, financial goals, and strategies.*
*Stick to your plan and avoid making impulsive decisions based on emotions.*
*Risk Management:*
*Set Stop-Loss and Take-Profit Levels:*
*Use stop-loss orders to limit potential losses and take-profit orders to secure profits.*
*Establish these levels based on your risk tolerance and market analysis.*
*Diversify Your Portfolio:*
*Avoid putting all your capital into a single trade; diversify across different currency pairs to spread risk.*
*Consider incorporating other asset classes to balance your overall investment portfolio.*
*Analysis Techniques:*
*Technical Analysis:*
*Analyze price charts and use technical indicators to identify trends and potential entry/exit points.*
*Common technical tools include moving averages, trendlines, and support/resistance levels.*
*Fundamental Analysis:*
*Monitor economic indicators, central bank policies, and geopolitical events influencing currency movements.*
*Stay informed about news that can impact the forex market.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Counterpoint to your plan to 'invest' in cryptocurrency: Don't.

Comment: Is it possible to know why

Comment: You can see my thoughts on the matter in the answer I've linked to your question as a possible duplicate. Long-story short, there is no inherent value mechanism for crypto-currency, and unlike "FIAT!!!!!" currencies, it lacks a singular powerful entity forcing its use whereby value is tied to that entity [unlike how fiat currencies are used to collect tax and therefore are tied to the strength of their governments {simplistically}]. Scams are common, transaction costs [including conversion in/out constantly] are high, volatility is high, and their use supports money laundering/organized crime.

Comment: @EsdrasZongo on top of what was said, if you're asking about *investments* you need to understand the *value*. If you don't know what a cryptocurrency is - then you're not investing, you're gambling. Generally in gambling, the house has the advantage and is always ahead. Are you the house?

Comment: Ok I understand thanks a lot